# How to identify column value change in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame as below that have data for strike_price and value.

```
    date        time    int_sp          value

1   20180903    09:16   11700           283.90
315 20180903    14:31   11700           273.85
316 20180903    14:32   11700           274.05
317 20180903    14:33   11600           295.35
390 20180904    09:31   11600           284.5
391 20180904    09:32   11500           304.15
403 20180904    09:44   11500           301.6
404 20180904    09:45   11600           282.4
405 20180904    09:46   11500           300.35
406 20180904    09:47   11500           300.35
407 20180904    09:48   11500           300.95
408 20180904    09:49   11500           301.3
409 20180904    09:50   11600           280.4
474 20180904    10:55   11600           279.25
475 20180904    10:56   11500           300.15
```

My first trade should always be a sell on the first record. Now, whenever strike price(int_sp) changes, I need to buy the sold position and create a new trade by selling at the new strike price.

This is my expected output.

```
sell_date   sell_time   buy_date    buy_time    int_sp      sell_price      buy_price
20180903    09:16       20180903    14:32       11700       283.90          274.05          
20180903    14:33       20180904    09:31       11600       295.35          284.5
20180904    09:32       20180904    09:44       11500       304.15          301.6
20180904    09:45       20180904    09:45       11600       282.4           282.4
20180904    09:46       20180904    09:49       11500       300.35          301.3   
20180904    09:50       20180904    10:55       11600       280.4           279.25
20180904    10:56       TBD         TBD         11500       300.15          TBD
```

I am very new to pandas and can't think of how to achieve this.
Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to get sell info

```
ndf = df.loc[df['int_sp'].diff().ne(0)].add_prefix('sell_').reset_index().copy()
```

Now, use mask

```
mask = df['int_sp'].diff().shift(-1).fillna(0).ne(0)
```

This mask filters on lagged values, which are the buy-related values. Then just assign

```
ndf.loc[:, 'buy_value'] = df.loc[mask, 'value'].reset_index(drop=True)
ndf.loc[:, 'buy_date'] = df.loc[mask, 'date'].reset_index(drop=True)
ndf.loc[:, 'buy_time'] = df.loc[mask, 'time'].reset_index(drop=True)


        sell_date   sell_time   sell_int_sp sell_value  buy_value   buy_date    buy_time
index                           
1       20180903    09:16       11700       283.90      274.05      20180903.0  14:32
317     20180903    14:33       11600       295.35      284.50      20180904.0  09:31
391     20180904    09:32       11500       304.15      301.60      20180904.0  09:44
404     20180904    09:45       11600       282.40      282.40      20180904.0  09:45
405     20180904    09:46       11500       300.35      301.30      20180904.0  09:49
409     20180904    09:50       11600       280.40      279.25      20180904.0  10:55
475     20180904    10:56       11500       300.15      NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Comment: where is `buy_time` column in your result?

Comment: @RafaelC, work like a charm. Thanks man! really appreciated you time and efforts.